# Make File: "Nothing to be done for 'all'" Not updating after change to source file

Tags: makefile

I am brand new to make files in linux and trying to provide a make file for a simple heap management program.

When executing the make command, it works to originally build my program, however after making changes to the source file quickfit.c, make doesnt recognize the change and says "make: Nothing to be done for 'all'."

Why is it not recompiling my software after changes? I have all my source files in a source folder and all my header files in a include folder.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -w -g
INCLUDE:= -Iinclude/
SOURCE:= source/quickfit.c \
         source/HeapTestEngine.o
EXE=QuickFit

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE):
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(SOURCE) -o $(EXE)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(EXE)` doesn't depend on anything. `make` does not infer this dependency for you, you have to declare it.

```
$(EXE): $(SOURCE)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(SOURCE) -o $(EXE)
```

You'll probably also want to declare dependencies on your header files as well.

Note: it's a bit odd to consider an object file as "source". `source/HeapTestEngine.o` should probably have its own target.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$(EXE):
```

Into:

```
$(EXE): $(SOURCE)
```